# Vue router beforeEach

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Problem is that the name gets undefined value I do not know why.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCDe3.png)

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.dir(to);
});
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the definition of the route you are navigating to when you get this? Did you define the route name?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have router.js file or something similar your route object would look something like this

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login', // this being the name
      component: () => import(whatever component),
      meta: {
       // some data goes here if needed
      }
    },
  ]
})
```

`name: 'login'` would be the undefined value you are seeing or what ever name you place there for whatever route